# How to run XCTest based tests under Instruments in Xcode 8 from Command Line?

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, instruments, xctest

In Xcode, right click on test in the test navigator and select "Profile "TestName"":
I can profile a tests in instruments
but I want to run it in command line to CI(to profile my app's cpu usage etc with xcuitest to do uiautomation).
Possible?